# Print total free memory from `free -m`

Tags: linux, grep, string

`free -m` currently puts out something like this.

[image]

I would like to know using `grep`/`awk` how we can get the total free amount. i.e. `9083`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/^-/ {print $4}' <(free -m)
9083
```

Be aware that in [procps-ng 3.3.10](http://sourceforge.net/projects/procps-ng/), the output format changes, and this line will then look like:

```
awk '/Mem:/ {print $4}' <(free -m)
9083
```

The amount of available memory can be accessed in the newer `procps-ng` in a different field:

```
awk '/Mem:/ {print $7}' <(free -m)
```

Comment: Which one is most suited for CentOS 7?

Comment: Use the first until procps-ng is updated, which should be some time away for Centos.

Comment: Seems you are right. The first one gave me accurate result.

Comment: @jasonwryan The second awk command printing from version procps-ng 3.3.10 is not printing the right value, the first is printing 9083 which is the real free mem(he calls it `total free amount`) from the buffers/cache line, in 3.3.10 it is named `available` and is the last column on the Mem: line. Your command is printing his free mem value of 160.

Comment: @somethingSomething that's becasue OP wants the "free" amount, "available" would be `$7`.

Comment: @jasonwryan Yes. I'm not giving you a hard time, just as I understand the question he gives you the value he's after 9083 in the picture.... and that value is not the same as free in the newer version. I learned this in the last 12 months so it's pretty clear in memory. The lower line in the picture.... the one he want's is the free mem on line two where buffers/cache is and as you can see if you check it out that line is not present in the new version of procps-ng, it's now called `available` positioned in the last column($7). (That is all available memory(buffers/cache included))

Comment: @somethingSomething oh, I see what you mean. I'll edit that in. Thanks.

Comment: There's no reason for the `<(…)` bashism; you could do those as `free -m |awk '/Mem:/ {print $4}'` etc.  Actually, it's preferable to avoid the regex, so you're best with `free -m |awk '$1 == "Mem:" { print $4 }'`. You can also use awk to determine which column is which in the event it changes again in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Just select `N`th row and `M`th column, eg:

```
free -m | awk 'NR==3{print $4}'
```

Comment: In procps-ng 3.3.10, this prints the total available swap...

Answer (score 1):

```
free -m | grep buffers/cache | awk -F" " '{ print $3 }'
free -m | grep buffers/cache | awk -F" " '{ print $4 }'
```

Comment: `awk` has pattern matching, you don't need the `grep` process...

Comment: Also, in 3.3.10, this prints nothing...

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
free -m | grep ^Mem | tr -s " " | cut -f4 -d" "
```